# JQuery.ajax succes function fadeTo not working in IE 10

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-10

I have the following function:

```
   $("#home").click(function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass('activeLink')) {
   return false;
   }
   $('.menu a').removeClass('activeLink');
   $(this).addClass('activeLink');
   $('.sidebar').click();
   var home = 'ok';

   //Send request to home.php
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'home.php',
    data: {
    home: home
    },
success: function(data) {
    $page.fadeTo(1000, 0, 'easeOutSine',function(){
        $(this).delay(500).html(data).fadeTo(1000,1,'easeOutSine');
    });
},
error: function(){
    alert('error');
    }
});
    return false;
}); //end home.click
```

The code is working perfectly fine in Mozilla and Chrome, but fadeTo is not working in IE 10, or any version, for that matter. I tried replacing the fadeTo() with fadeIn() and fadeOut(), but that didn't help. I tried changing opacity with JQuery, still nothing. The html that is returned from the request is as follows:

```
<div class="home">
    <div class='overlay'>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.page {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}

.home {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/background1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.overlay {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/pattern.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

I tried moving the fading things in a separate function, result is still the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I got it working when I changed the selector from 
    `$page = $(".page");`
to
    `$('.page div').fadeTo(...)`
I had to add another div. If I select directly `.page`, it is not working. Neverimind, 
this finally sort of worked in IE. The effect is fading out smoothly and the fading in pretty swiftly, not like how it behaves in Chrome and Firefox. However, I am going yo go with it. The strange thing is that in IE 9 mode the effects work OK - IE 10 is experiencing problems.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

```
success: function(data) {
    $page.fadeTo(1000, 0, 'easeOutSine',function(){
```

to something else ...

for instance

```
success: function(data) {
    $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0, 'easeOutSine',function(){
```

or

```
success: function(data) {
    $(document).fadeTo(1000, 0, 'easeOutSine',function(){
```

or any existing element.... currently it can't find "$page" that is nothing to your script

Comment: Sorry you can actually also do $.page

Comment: $page is defined above the function, and is a reference to the element with class .page